# Showing that $I-M$ is an invertible matrix if $\|M\| < 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $M$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\|\cdot\|$ some vector norm. Show that the matrix $I-M$ is invertible if $\|M\| < 1.$

I'm somewhat confused about this problem. How can I relate the fact that $I-M$ is invertible if the norm of $M$ is less than $1$?

Comment: $I+M+M^{2}+...$ converges and its sum is the inverse if $I-M$.

Comment: This isn't true. Consider $\|M\|=\frac{1}{2n}\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}m_{ij}^2}$. This is a vector norm. When all elements of $M$ are equal to $1$, $\|M\|=\frac12<1$ but $M$ is not invertible. The statement can be corrected by changing $\|\cdot\|$ to a *submultiplicative* matrix norm (a norm is called submultiplicative if $\|AB\|\le\|A\|\|B\|$ for any two square matrices $A$ and $B$). In particular, it is true if $\|\cdot\|$ is *induced* from a vector norm, i.e. if the norm is defined by $\|M\|=\max_{\|x\|'\le1}\|Mx\|'$ for some vector norm $\|\cdot\|'$ defined on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: This is a particular case of [Neumann Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series)

Comment: @user1551 it is possible that the asker is using "vector norm" to refer to a norm on $\Bbb R^n$, so that $\|\cdot \|$ (when applied to matrices) refers to the norm induced by the vector norm.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by $\lVert M\rVert$ you mean the operator norm, i.e. the maximum of $x\to \lVert Mx\rVert$ on the unit sphere. Notice two things:

1. To say that $I-M$ is invertible is equivalent to saying that $M$ has no fixed points ($Mx=x$ has no solutions).
2. To say that $\lVert M\rVert<1$ is to say that $M$ strictly shrinks everything, i.e. $\lVert Mx\rVert<\lVert x\rVert$ for all $x$ (notice the inequality is strict!).

If you can show (1) and (2) are true, the conclusion should be straightforward.

As to your conceptual question, "what does the operator norm have to do with being invertible", maybe it will be less surprising if you remember that we're only showing implication, not equivalence. Having operator norm less than $1$ is a simple sufficient condition for being injective, but not a necessary condition.

Answer (score 0):

For intuition consider $M$ diagonalizable: $M = Q \Sigma Q^{-1}$, where $\Sigma$ is a digonal matrix of the eigenvalues.
Then $I-M = Q(I-\Sigma)Q^{-1}$, that is, the $i$th eigenvalue is $1-e_i$ where $e_i$ is the $i$th eigenvalue of $M$.
The condition $\|M\|<1$ is the same as requiring that all $|e_i|<1$, hence all the new eigenvalues are different from 0, and so $I-M$ is invertible.